# MEDLINE®/PubMed dataset as a relational database (e.g., MySQL)

Tags: data-request, pubmed

I am looking for a way to obtain the MEDLINE®/PubMed dataset (i.e., metadata of PubMed papers) as a relational database (e.g., MySQL). The [MEDLINE®/PubMed can be downloaded as XML files](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/license/license.html), but I would prefer to write SQL queries when using it. I am fine if it involves running some script to convert.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491056/how-to-import-xml-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-xml-load-function

Comment: @albert Sure, here is an excerpt https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofcw6xniy0f1nyv/medline16n0806.xml.zip?dl=0

Comment: im fiddling with xmlutils but hitting some issues. this file is massive

Comment: @albert here is a much small excerpt: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcjoggt1wa5u7z9/medline16n0147.xml_selected.xml?dl=0 (Total of the XML files is ~120 GB, which I believe I cannot share due to PubMed license)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41891/discussion-between-albert-and-franck-dernoncourt).